# Row and column discrepancy for excel tables in R

Tags: r

I am attempting to perform some functional diversity analyses for bee communities in Northern Ontario. I am using the R package SYNCSA and attempting to calculate Rao's Diversity. An error keeps popping up saying that "There are species from community data that are not on traits matrix".

In order to perform the analysis with the function rao.diversity, I needed to make a table of abundance data (e.g.  the 2 bee communities and how many of each species therein) and a table of traits (e.g. each species in the community and their pollen specificity, nesting behaviour, etc., which contains ordinal data that I have ranked numerically).

Now, there is a rule using this function that the species names, which are in columns in the community (abundance) data, must match exactly the species names of the rows in the trait data. When I got this error, I immediately made sure the columns of the community data matched the rows of the trait data, and they do, as far as I can see. I also tried the function organize.syncsa, which is supposed to fix the column/row not matching, only to get the error message "comm must contain only numeric or binary variables". My comm (that is, community data) does indeed only contain numeric variables, so I don't know what I am doing wrong there either.

The following are ASCII text representations of my 2 tables for community data and trait data respectively:

```
dput(community.data.raos)
structure(list(X = structure(2:1, .Label = c("Akimiski", "Far North"
), class = "factor"), Andrena.algida = 1:0, Andrena.barbilabris = 1:0, 
    Andrena.frigida = 1:0, Anthophora.terminalis = 0:1, Bombus.flavidus = c(6L, 
    0L), Bombus.flavifrons = 2:1, Bombus.frigidus = c(65L, 27L
    ), Bombus.melanopygus = c(0L, 8L), Bombus.mixtus = 1:2, Bombus.sandersoni = c(21L, 
    0L), Bombus.sylvicola = c(4L, 17L), Bombus.ternarius = c(5L, 
    15L), Bombus.terricola = c(8L, 0L), Bombus.vagans = c(9L, 
    0L), Colletes.americanus = 0:1, Colletes.impunctatus = c(0L, 
    6L), Colletes.nigrifrons = c(1L, 5L), Halictus.ligatus = c(0L, 
    2L), Halictus.rubicundus = c(2L, 0L), Halictus.tripartitus = 1:0, 
    Halictus.virgatellus = c(2L, 12L), Lasioglossum.ephialtum = c(2L, 
    0L), Lasioglossum.laevissimum = 1:0, Lasioglossum.inconditum = c(5L, 
    0L), Lasioglossum.quebecense = 1:0, Coelioxys.sodalis = 2:1, 
    Hoplitis.albifrons = 1:0, Megachile.circumcincta = 0:1, Megachile.frigida = 2:3, 
    Megachile.gemula = 1:2, Megachile.lapponica = c(1L, 1L), 
    Megachile.melanophaea = c(0L, 3L), Megachile.montivaga = 1:0, 
    Megachile.perihirta = c(0L, 3L), Megachile.relativa = 1:2, 
    Osmia.bucephala = c(1L, 1L), Osmia.laticeps = 1:0, Osmia.nigrifrons = c(2L, 
    0L), Osmia.nigriventris = c(5L, 1L), Osmia.paradisica = c(0L, 
    8L), Osmia.tarsata = 1:0, Osmia.tersula = 1:0), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))


dput(trait.table.raos)
structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
24L, 26L, 25L, 27L, 15L, 23L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L), .Label = c("Andrena.algida ", 
"Andrena.barbilabris ", "Andrena.frigida ", "Anthophora.terminalis", 
"Bombus.flavidus", "Bombus.flavifrons ", "Bombus.frigidus ", 
"Bombus.melanopygus ", "Bombus.mixtus", "Bombus.sandersoni ", 
"Bombus.sylvicola", "Bombus.ternarius ", "Bombus.terricola ", 
"Bombus.vagans ", "Coelioxys.sodalis ", "Colletes.americanus", 
"Colletes.impunctatus", "Colletes.nigrifrons", "Halictus.ligatus", 
"Halictus.rubicundus", "Halictus.tripartitus", "Halictus.virgatellus ", 
"Hoplitis.albifrons ", "Lasioglossum.ephialtum", "Lasioglossum.inconditum", 
"Lasioglossum.laevissimum ", "Lasioglossum.quebecense ", "Megachile.circumcincta ", 
"Megachile.frigida", "Megachile.gemula", "Megachile.lapponica", 
"Megachile.melanophaea", "Megachile.montivaga ", "Megachile.perihirta", 
"Megachile.relativa", "Osmia.bucephala", "Osmia.laticeps", "Osmia.nigrifrons", 
"Osmia.nigriventris", "Osmia.paradisica ", "Osmia.tarsata", "Osmia.tersula "
), class = "factor"), Pollen.Specificity = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Tongue.Length = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Sociality = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Nesting.Behavior = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L), Average.Female.ITD = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.64, NA, 
3.02, NA, 4.52, 3.21, 3.67, 4.17, 4.14, 3.59, NA, 2.15, 1.97, 
NA, 2.21, NA, 1.79, NA, NA, 1.43, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3.14, 3.57, 
3.21, 3.24, NA, 3.92, NA, 4, NA, 3.29, 3.86, 3.09, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

And an example of the error I am getting:

```
rao.diversity(comm = community.data.raos, traits = trait.table.raos)
Error in rao.diversity(comm = community.data.raos, traits = trait.table.raos) : 

 There are species from community data that are not on traits matrix
>
```

The rao.diversity function should produce a series of small tables with a value between 0 and 1 for each site (in my case, there are two such sites) indicating different measures of diversity. Instead, I am getting the error message that "There are species from community data that are not on traits matrix."

Comment: I don't have the package, but looking at the docs and the code on Github, at the very least you need to get rid of the first column of `community.data.raos`, column   `X`. You could convert it to `row.names`, perhaps, if you want to retain the information, with `row.names(community.data.rao) = community.data.rao$X`, then delete the column with `community.data.rao$X = NULL`. Similarly, you'll need to convert the `X` column of `trait.table.raos` to row names. [Look at the top of the function](https://github.com/vanderleidebastiani/SYNCSA/blob/master/R/rao.diversity.R) to see why.

Comment: You also might need to do some clean-up. Several of the species names  in your trait table have trailing spaces, e.g., `"Bombus.frigidus "`, but the column names of the community data do not. The `trimws()` function will trim whitespace for you.

Comment: I will give this a try to see if it works. These are good ideas. I will post again if the problem persists or close the thread if this fixes the issue.

Comment: @Gregor, this worked. Now I just need to figure out how to upvote you and mark this question as answered.

Comment: Glad to hearit! I didn't want to post an answer since I hadn't downloaded the package to test, but with your confirmation I'll do a brief write-up, which you can then accept. I'll try to get to it this afternoon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make it super clear, but looking [at the code of the function](https://github.com/vanderleidebastiani/SYNCSA/blob/master/R/rao.diversity.R#L91), we can see that the column names of the community object must match the *row names* of the traits object. With that info, we can look at your inputs and identify a few problems:

- You community object has a first column `X` that is not a species. Get rid of it, turning the values into row names if you want to keep that information.
- Your traits object has the species in the first column, but they need to be row names.
- Your species labels are inconsistent between the two objects: in the trait table a few of them have trailing white space. Use `trimws()` to get rid of that so that the matches are exact.

If you continue to have problems, you might want to look at `setdiff(row.names(trait.table.raos), colnames(community.data.rao))` and the reverse, `setdiff(colnames(community.data.rao), row.names(trait.table.raos))`, to make sure the match between species names is exact. Both of those statements should return no results.